# Spring security login error "Request method 'POST' not supported"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-security, thymeleaf

I've looked at every related question I could find, but haven't been able to find an answer that works in my scenario. I'm using a Spring WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, and I was able to authenticate a single user type, but after configuring my SecurityConfig class to handle multiple user types, I'm getting a "Request method 'POST' not supported" error even though I still the same URL for formLogin().loginPage(URL...).

I have 4 static classes of orders 1, 2, 3 and 4, although the first 2 are simply for permitting unauthenticated users to URLs with patterns `/` for home and `/account/*` for other things. All of these static classes are working appropriately, and when a URL is visited with patterns `/company/*` and `/candidate/*` the user is directed to the appropriate login pages to log in.

This is where the problem now occurs. I am using "/account/candidateLogin" and "/account/companyLogin" as the args in formLogin().loginPage(arg), but the same controller method I used before is no longer working properly. I am getting a 405 error and the console displays `o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound : Request method 'POST' not supported`.

Here is the relevant code, and thank you in advance:

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers( "/images/**",
            "/vendor/**",
            "/app.css",
            "/app.js",
            "/favicon.png");
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class HomePageSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends 
    WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/")
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();

       }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class AccountSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends 
    WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/account/*")
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();

        }
    }


    @Configuration
    @Order(3)
    public static class CompanySecurityConfigurationAdapter extends 
    WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private CompanyService companyService;

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(companyService);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/company/*")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .hasRole("COMPANY")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/account/companyLogin")
                .successHandler(companyLoginSuccessHandler())
                .failureHandler(companyLoginFailureHandler())
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
        }

        public AuthenticationSuccessHandler companyLoginSuccessHandler() {
            return (request, response, authentication) -> response.sendRedirect("/company/companyProfile");
        }

        public AuthenticationFailureHandler companyLoginFailureHandler() {
            return (request, response, exception) -> {
                request.getSession().setAttribute("flash", new FlashMessage("Incorrect username and/or password. Please try again.", FlashMessage.Status.FAILURE));
                response.sendRedirect("/account/companyLogin");
            };
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(4)
    public static class CandidateSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private CandidateService candidateService;

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(candidateService);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/candidate/*")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .hasRole("CANDIDATE")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/account/candidateLogin")
                .successHandler(candidateLoginSuccessHandler())
                .failureHandler(candidateLoginFailureHandler())
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
        }

        public AuthenticationSuccessHandler candidateLoginSuccessHandler() {
            return (request, response, authentication) -> response.sendRedirect("/candidate/candidateProfile");
        }

        public AuthenticationFailureHandler candidateLoginFailureHandler() {
            return (request, response, exception) -> {
                request.getSession().setAttribute("flash", new FlashMessage("Incorrect username and/or password. Please try again.", FlashMessage.Status.FAILURE));
                response.sendRedirect("/account/candidateLogin");
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller for login URIs. These are the same, just one for the candidate login and one for the company**

```
@Controller()
public class AccountController {

    @Autowired
    private CandidateService candidateService;

    @Autowired
    private CompanyService companyService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/account/candidateLogin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String candidateLoginForm(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        model.addAttribute("candidate", new Candidate());
        try {
            Object flash = request.getSession().getAttribute("flash");
            model.addAttribute("flash", flash);
            model.addAttribute("action", "/account/candidateLogin");
            model.addAttribute("submit","Login");

            request.getSession().removeAttribute("flash");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Flash session attribute must not exist. Do nothing and proceed.
        }
        return "account/candidateLogin";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/account/companyLogin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginCompanyForm(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        model.addAttribute("company", new Company());
        try {
            Object flash = request.getSession().getAttribute("flash");
            model.addAttribute("flash", flash);
            model.addAttribute("action", "/account/companyLogin");
            model.addAttribute("submit","Login");

            request.getSession().removeAttribute("flash");
        }  catch (Exception e) {
            //Flash session attribute must not exist. Do nothing and proceed.
        }
        return "account/companyLogin";
    }
```

**Login HTML file. I'm just including one since the only difference is variable names.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head th:replace="layout :: head('explore')"></head>
<body>
<div th:replace="layout :: nav"></div>
<div th:replace="layout :: login"></div>


<h1 style="margin-left: 25%">Company Login</h1>
<div class="grayContainer">
    <div th:fragment="login">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
                <div th:replace="layout :: flash"></div>
                <form th:action="@{${action}}" th:object="${company}" method="post">
                    <div class="input-field" style="width: 70%; margin: 0 auto;">
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{username}" placeholder="Username/Email"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field" style="width: 70%; margin: 0 auto;">
                        <input type="password" th:field="*{password}" placeholder="Password"/>
                    </div>
                    <button class="button" type="${submit}" style="text-align: center;">Login</button>Forgot password?
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div th:replace="layout :: scripts"></div>

</body>
```

**EDIT**

As a few people suggested, I changed the method in the request mapping for the login form to POST instead of GET and enabled security logging. Now I can't access the login page at all, it gives me a 405 error and this is the security debugger log:

```
************************************************************


2018-03-06 14:27:48.820  INFO 4495 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] Spring Security Debugger                 : 

************************************************************

Request received for GET '/account/candidateLogin':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@4cf3f981

servletPath:/account/candidateLogin
pathInfo:null
headers: 
host: localhost:8080
connection: keep-alive
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2)AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
referer: http://localhost:8080/account/selectType
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cookie: JSESSIONID=58FD34AB4F9796EC523C355C0A51ED49


Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CsrfFilter
  LogoutFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]


************************************************************


2018-03-06 14:27:48.829  WARN 4495 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'GET' not supported
```

Comment: Update controller method annotations to - @RequestMapping(value = "/account/companyLogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)  and  @RequestMapping(value = "/account/candidateLogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)

Comment: Hey @RameshFadatare I answered your comment in amRika's response because you both suggested the same fix.

Comment: @dur I just now tried that and when I have the controller mapping with the method set as method = RequestMethod.GET, the debugger is showing this request: Request received for POST '/account/candidateLogin': and then o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'POST' not supported. But when I switch the method to POST, I get this: Request received for GET '/account/candidateLogin': and then o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound  : Request method 'GET' not supported.

Comment: @dur if I understand correctly, having 'account/candidatLogin' set as the .loginPage() in the SecurityConfig class means that once the submit button in that form is pressed, for which the method is POST, Spring security will intercept the post and attempt to authenticate the user and then either direct to the success or failure url. It worked with this exact controller when I had a single role, but after adding multiple roles for Order(1), Order(2)... something changed and the same controller setup no longer works.

Comment: @dur Do you know why it would have worked before with the method in the controller set as GET but does not work now? Even when the form in the HTML file has always been set as POST? I could post the old code that I had working correctly for one user if it helps. Also, did you see the debug log that I added to the question?

Comment: @dur That did it!!! Thank you so much. There must have been a conflict where I was having Spring security permit all users to the login pages in a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter of higher order. So the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter for authenticating users was never reached.

Comment: @dur if you post that explanation as an answer then I'll accept it and up vote it. Thank you!

Comment: @CBruenger If you have managed to solve this problem, Can you post the solution for it. I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

for the request mapping

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/account/candidateLogin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/account/companyLogin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

They are mapped with GET method of the request while in ur form

```
<form th:action="@{${action}}" th:object="${company}" method="post">
```

its POST.

Comment: I tried this before and just now tried it again but that is not fixing the issue. This produces the error 'o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound   : Request method 'GET' not supported' when I try to access the login form. Do I somehow need to have GET and POST versions?

Comment: Also, having the request method set as GET in the mapping but having it set as POST in the HTML file definitely was how it was working previously before configuring the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to handle multiple user types with different orders. I had developed that code by working through a TeamTreehouse tutorial and I have their repo which similarly has the controller request method as GET and the /login HTML file method set as POST.

Comment: do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try passing CSRF token from your form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

in you java code, the request method is GET,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/account/companyLogin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

while in you html code ,the request method is POST,

```
<form th:action="@{${action}}" th:object="${company}" method="post">
```

you should keep them the same.

Comment: Thanks for your response. amRika suggested the same answer above but I explained the problem that produces. Do you have any suggestions based on the error that I get after changing GET to POST as the request method in the mapping?

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions?